# Code Analysis Microsoft.Naming warnings on the abbreviation "ID"

Tags: c#, .net, code-analysis, fxcop

I have been using ID (capital case) in all my property names and sql column names. Now i have started to correct all code analysis warnings to enforce new coding guidelines on the team.

Is there a way to add ID to a dictionary where it wont generate warnings (such as [CA1709](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182240.aspx))?

Example -

```
Warning 4   CA1709 : Microsoft.Naming : Correct the casing of 'ID' in member name 'City.CityID' by changing it to 'Id'.
'Id' is an abbreviation and therefore is not subject to acronym casing guideline.
```

Comment: maybe even a ["custom dictionary"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb514188.aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up adding this in a custom dictionary - and it worked. Thanks Alastair Pitts

```
<Dictionary>
  <Acronyms>
    <CasingExceptions>
      <Acronym>ID</Acronym>   <!-- Identifier -->
    </CasingExceptions>
  </Acronyms>
</Dictionary>
```

And it also helps me add other spellings which it complains about - like facebook, twitter etc.